# Running Docker redis instance can't access redis

Tags: powershell, docker, redis

On Windows 10, I open up powershell and type:

```
docker pull redis
docker run --name some-redis -d redis
```

So I have a docker container running with redis on it.  How do I access it?  How do I run ping so I can see pong?  I want to add values and then read the values.  I don't see any documentation on this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looking back at my question, it is very poorly written. I want to be able to access the redis instance external from the container.  I would like to be able to fire up powershell and get or set a key.  The problem that I am trying to figure out is how to access this redis container in a distributed system.

Answer (score 3):

[Docs of redis image](https://store.docker.com/images/redis?tab=description) has detailed description of how to run and access redis container. Basically you have the following options:

- Go inside your redis container with the following command and then play with `redis-cli`:

  `docker exec -it some-redis bash`
- Map redis port to host when launching the redis container

  `docker run -d --name some-redis -p 6379:6379 redis`

  Then you can just connect to redis like it's running on your host machine
- Container link, connect to redis within another container on the same host machine

  `docker run -it --link some-redis:redis --rm redis redis-cli -h redis -p 6379`